# Custom slider with emojis

Tags: dart, flutter

I am building a flutter app and want to create a custom slider with emojis very similar to the reflectly app. I am attaching a screenshot , as you change the slider the emoji changes. I am pretty new to flutter and am struggling with the slider widget

[image: slider]

Comment: Please be a bit more explicit and add some code showing what you've tried or currently have. What exactly are you having trouble with - getting the slider to show up, or getting it to look exactly like the screenshot? Or are you having trouble with getting the emoji to change when the slider is changed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like that:

[image]

I didn't use images for emojis faces but could put you in the right direction.

Full code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const _emojis = ['','','','','',''];

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  double _value = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: new LinearGradient(
                colors: [Colors.teal, Colors.tealAccent],
                begin: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                end: Alignment.topRight
            )
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                '${_emojis[_value.toInt()]}',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                child: Container(
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(_emojis[0], softWrap: true),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Slider(
                          value: _value,
                          //label: _emojis[_value.toInt()],
                          min: 0.0,
                          max: 5.0,
                          divisions: 5,

                          onChangeStart: (double value) {
                            print('Start value is ' + value.toString());
                          },
                          onChangeEnd: (double value) {
                            print('Finish value is ' + value.toString());
                          },
                          onChanged: (double value) {
                            setState(() {
                              _value = value;
                            });
                          },
                          activeColor: Colors.white,
                          inactiveColor: Colors.black45,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(_emojis[5], softWrap: true,)
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for. Works great.

Comment: shadowsheep how did you add the emojis in the code? Is it an extension for VSCode? I want to change them but my extensions for emojis arent working

Comment: @SamCromer I’m on osx (ctrl+cmd+space) [link](https://buffer.com/library/emojis-keyboard-shortcut-mac-windows). But I suggest you to use images from assets so that they will be the same on any devices. Btw I code with Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

[This reviewpage animation](https://www.mindinventory.com/blog/create-review-page-custom-widgets-with-flutter/) is close to 90% of the reflectly animation.